# correct approach for XSL templates

Tags: xslt

I started on `XSL` a few weeks ago, and I have developed a pattern for templates.

My templates will handle some of the content of the matched element, then pass off its children to other templates that might match them.

But I exclude elements that it has already dealt with, so as not to process the same elements again.

For example:

```
<xsl:template name="DEFINITION" match="DEFINITION">
    
        <xsl:element name="body">
            <xsl:attribute name="break">before</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="defn">
                <xsl:attribute name="id" />
                <xsl:attribute name="scope" />
                <xsl:value-of select="DEFINEDTERM" />
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="TEXT" />
        </xsl:element>
        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::DEFINEDTERM|self::TEXT)]" />
        
</xsl:template>
```

Is this the correct approach? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't need any `xsl:element` or `xsl:attribute` but could just use literal result elements and attribute value templates e.g. `<body break="before"><xsl:apply-templates select="DEFINEDTERM, TEXT"/></body>` (that is XSLT 2 or 3, for XSLT 1 use `<body break="before"><xsl:apply-templates select="DEFINEDTERM"/> <xsl:apply-templates select="TEXT"/></body>`) plus obviously a template

```
<xsl:template matched="DEFINEDTERM">
  <defn id="" scope="">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </defn>
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 2/3 you can write `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::DEFINEDTERM|self::TEXT)]" />` as e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="* except (DEFINEDTERM, TEXT)"/>`.

Comment: In XSLT 1, is `not(self::DEFINEDTERM|self::TEXT)` equivalent to `not(self::DEFINEDTERM or self::TEXT)`?  Which is preferred?

Comment: I have edited my code to better reflect my original question.

Comment: @CJ7, how are the two questions in your first comment related to my answer? If you have additional questions raise them as separate questions.

Comment: @CJ7, I have adapted my suggestion to your edit.

Comment: My question was more about whether my general approach is correct. Should I handle the element, then apply templates to its children while excluding elements already handled?

Comment: You didn't show the input samples nor the wanted output but if you want to map a `DEFINITION` element to a `body` populated by processing some child elements and some further content after the `body` processing further child elements you need some way to exclude nodes from being processed twice; your chosen way seems fine, your way of creating result elements is way too verbose and I would keep as much code as possible in templates matching separate elements, so therefore I also suggested the change to literal result elements and an additional template for `DEFINEDTERM`.